# Open project folder in PyCharm using python script

Tags: python, windows, command-line, pycharm

Is there any way to open folder in PyCharm using python script?

I wanted to Automate below process through python code.

1. create virtual environment in folder
2. install packages
3. Open folder in PyCharm

step 1 and 2 is done.

I tried using command line `pycharm.bat <folder_path>` it Opens a project folder in PyCharm but the issue is When I close command line window then PyCharm window also closed automatically.

Is there any Solution?

Comment: are you using 64 bit system? If you are, you can try doing `pycharm64.exe <folder_location>` rather then using the bat script.

Comment: @sqz I tried but still command is running, But When I close command prompt PyCharm window is still open. Thanks!